# Javascript/TypeScript - Can I add class properties from an array?

Tags: javascript, typescript, xlsx

Thank you for the help in advance. I am working in TypeScript, I'd assume any JS solution also works. I'd like to make something like this:

```
class ExcelData {
  'Id 1': items[0].id,
  'Quantity 1': items[0].quantity,
  'Id 2': items[1].id,
  'Quantity 2': items[1].quantity
  //...
  'Id 40': items[39].id,
  'Quantity 40': items[39].quantity,
}
```

I am trying to use it with the 'xlsx' module to export project data into an Excel sheet. It is necessary for this module that it is a class, rather than several arrays. I could type it out manually, but there is 7 properties for every item and this would be very ugly code. It is also possible that I am later asked to add more items.
If it were Python, I could do something like this bc classes and dictionaries are different things:

```
excel_data = {}
for i in range (40):
  excel_data['Id '+ str(i)] = items[i].id
  excel_data['Quantity '+ str(i)] = items[i].quantity
```

What is a Typescript alternative?

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like a very poor fit for a class. Are you sure it needs to be one? With a plain object (`{}`) you can write something almost the same as your python code.

Comment: It's not clear why you need a class for this. If you were to get your data into the class how would the module call it? And how different is a JS object to a Python dictionary? Finally, this has nothing to do with TS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible that you are looking for [index-signatures](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures). In JavaScript/Typescript objects are more comparable to Python dictionaries than classes, and for data stores such as this, I would recommend them.

You can create your desired data store and access its properties like so:

```
interface ExcelData {
    [property: string]: string | number | undefined;
}

const data: ExcelData = {};

data.id1 = "123-420";
data.quantity1 = 69;
```

It seems odd to want to have `"Quantity-*"` as a property though. A structure that uses ids to lookup and set quantities would look like this:

```
interface ExcelData {
    [id: string]: number | undefined;
}

const data: ExcelData = {};

data.someId = 69;
```

Lastly, you *can* do what you are trying to do with a class like so:

```
class MyClass {
    [property: string]: string | number | undefined;
}

const myInstance = new MyClass();

myInstance.id1 = "123-420";
myInstance.quantity1 = 69;
```

Comment: Thank you Jordan! I tried your 2nd offering, it worked perfectly. Have a good day/evening/night